# ElasticSearch - Java API - Truncate Type

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm looking for truncate a Type.
I found how delete an Index by the admin client.
But i don't find any way to truncate a type in the Java API

Comment: If you're using ES 1.x, then you can use the [delete mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-delete-mapping.html), otherwise this is [not possible anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-delete-mapping.html) since ES 2.x onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ES 1.x, then you can use the [delete mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-delete-mapping.html).
Otherwise this is [not possible anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-delete-mapping.html) since ES 2.x onwards.

The reasons are [explained here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring)

> it is no longer possible to delete a type mapping (along with the documents of that type). Even after removing a mapping, information about the deleted fields continues to exist at the Lucene level, which can cause index corruption if fields of the same name are added later on.